# JPA @ForeginKey mapping has no constraints at all?

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys

I may have totally missunderstood ForegignKey in JPA. But in a real database, when your table A has a foreign key to another table B. Then doesn't that key have to exist in table B when persisting/merging table A?

Here's an example of my issue:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    String name;

    // getters and setters....
}


@Entity
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Person.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    Person person;

    // getters and setters
}
```

In my world, a Person should have to exist in the database for the Pet to be able to be saved.But no, I can persist a Pet instance with Person=null without any problem. Now surely I could mark Person reference as @NotNull or optional=false but that is not what I want to acchieve. I want to make sure that when I persist a Pet, the Owning Person exists. How should I do this? A 2 way mapping using @OneToMany in Person is not something I can do in this case since I have around 20+ entities with foreign key constraints to "Person"